# Bootstrap div is not in right place

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

[image]Can someone please explain to me why this is happening? My mobile views work fine but it breaks to the attached pic when I expand the window.The code for both cards is literally identical as shown below:

```
<!-- This is the view for the page: -->
<div class="col-12 col-md-9">
  <div class="col-12 d-flex align-items-center mb-3">
    <span class="h2"> Spread the Knowledge </span>
    <%= link_to fa_icon("edit"), new_discussion_path, class: "profile-link fa-2x"  %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4>Answered Questions</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <%= render "answered_disc" %>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer text-center d-none">
        See all
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4>Unanswered Questions</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <%= render "unanswered_disc" %>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer text-center d-none">
        See all
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Both partials display the following code:

```
<% @discussions.each do |discussion| %>
    <% if discussion.parent_id.nil? && discussion.resolved == true %>
        <div class="list-group-item">
          <div class="row">

             <div class="wadinfo col-xs-12 col-md-9 mb-4">
                 <%= link_to discussion_path(discussion), class: 'profile-link' do %>
                        <h6 class="small"><%= discussion.content  %></h6>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
             </div>

             <div class="actions">
                        <% if discussion.resolved == false %>
                        <%= link_to 'Answer', discussion_path(discussion), class: 'profile-link' %>
                        <% else %>
                        <%= link_to 'Contribute', discussion_path(discussion), class: 'profile-link' %>
                        <% end %>
             </div>

          </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<!-- Code for menu -->
<div class="row row-sidebar">
  <div class="col-12 mb-3 text-center">
  </div>

  <div class="col-12">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <% sidebar_elements.each do |element| %>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="<%= element[:link] %>">
          <%= element[:name] %>
        </a>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The sidebar is rendered as a partial in a manifest file:

```
<% content_for :sub_layout do %>
  <div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="d-none d-md-flex col-3 align-items-start">
        <%= render "wads/sidebar" %>
    </div>

    <%= yield %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render template: 'layouts/application' %>
```

Very confused as the code is identical

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hjm33q84/2/ - here's a fiddle, however the problem is not being replicated by the fiddle

Comment: what is the code for the menu, because fiddle does not have it at all

Comment: @O.Don also you may try using `float-right` class

Comment: I've updated the question to include menu code. float-right moves it over but it is not aligned and the width is also different from the first div. I'm struggling to understand why these divs would display differently with the same code?

Answer (score 1):

When I try to pretty format your partial `erb` code, it seems broken. I guess it can be the reason because the browser will try to correct the broken HTML, hence the structure might go wrong

```
<!-- This block seems broken -->
  <div class="wadinfo col-xs-12 col-md-9 mb-4">
      <%= link_to discussion_path(discussion), class: 'profile-link' do %>
             <h6 class="small"><%= discussion.content  %></h6>
         </div>
 <% end %><!-- The link_to block has an incorrect closing </div> -->
</div>
```

I think after correcting it, your code should work as expected.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. unfortunately, correcting the div did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the divs with class `col-xs-12` in separate rows, i.e. in divs with class `row`:

Your code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
        ...
```

Fixed code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
            ...
```